# Regexp for extracting data in parenthesis and commas

Tags: python, regex

So, i have this :

> "( ABC,2004 )"

And I would need to extract ABC in a variable and 2004 in another.
So what I have for now is this:

> In: re.compile(r'([^)]*,').findall("(
> ABC,2004 )")
>
> Out: ['( ABC,']

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your inputs are always like that (begin with "( ", end with " )"), you can have your values as:

```
input_text.strip(" ()").split(",")

>>> "( ABC,2004 )".strip(" ()").split(",")
['ABC', '2004']
```

This will consume any parentheses at the edges *inside* the outer parentheses.

Also, if the commas can be surrounded/succeeded by spaces, you can:

```
[item.strip() for item in input_text.strip(" ()").split(",")]
```

Comment: This is a simple, elegant solution and... look ma, no regexp!

Comment: Agreed. Though I love regexps (really) a large part of Python is knowing when not to use them.

Comment: as jathanism says, 'look ma, no regexp!' 
thank you TZ, its perfect

Answer (score 2):

Try just looking for "word" characters:

```
>> re.compile(r'\w+').findall("( ABC,2004 )")
['ABC', '2004']
```